# Random sampling with numpy works but cupy gives "Unsupported dtype <U20"

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I am trying translate my negative sampling code in numpy to cupy.

First I have following import in my jupyter notebook:

```
import cupy as cp
```

I have a list of strings my jupyter notebook:

```
In: l = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'cccccccccccccccccccc']
```

I want to randomly sample from these words. So I tried:

```
In: cp.random.choice(l)
```

But it gave following error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-ecf4cf343af7> in <module>
----> 1 cp.random.choice(l)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/random/_sample.py in choice(a, size, replace, p)
    188     """
    189     rs = _generator.get_random_state()
--> 190     return rs.choice(a, size, replace, p)
    191 
    192 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/random/_generator.py in choice(self, a, size, replace, p)
   1025                 raise ValueError('a must be greater than or equal to 0')
   1026         else:
-> 1027             a = cupy.array(a, copy=False)
   1028             if a.ndim != 1:
   1029                 raise ValueError('a must be 1-dimensional or an integer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/_creation/from_data.py in array(obj, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)
     44 
     45     """
---> 46     return _core.array(obj, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)
     47 
     48 
...
cupy/_core/core.pyx in cupy._core.core.array()

cupy/_core/core.pyx in cupy._core.core._array_default()

ValueError: Unsupported dtype <U20
```

I checked if I can create a cupy list out of this python list:

```
In: words = cp.array(l)
```

But it gave me same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-8c7f71b29b1c> in <module>
----> 1 words = cp.array(l)
      2 # probs = cp.array(list(noiseDistribution.values()))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cupy/_creation/from_data.py in array(obj, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)
     44 
     45     """
---> 46     return _core.array(obj, dtype, copy, order, subok, ndmin)
     47 
     48 

cupy/_core/core.pyx in cupy._core.core.array()

cupy/_core/core.pyx in cupy._core.core.array()

cupy/_core/core.pyx in cupy._core.core._array_default()

ValueError: Unsupported dtype <U20
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

You can try out above code in [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UKsrnhAYFJrbg6h4dDPiEOx1qLyLvNs5?usp=sharing). Make sure to change runtime to GPU from menu `Runtime > Change runtime type`. Then only you will be able to import cupy.

**PS:**

My list `l` actually contains real words instead of dummy words shown above:

```
In: l
Out: ['emma',
      'jane',
      'austen',
      'woodhouse',
       'handsome',
      'clever',
      'rich',
      'comfortable',
      'home',
      'happy']
```

I have set it to dummy list of length 20 strings to replicate exact error.

Also note that the equivalent numpy sampling works just fine:

```
In:  np.random.choice(l) # works
Out: 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
```

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that `cp` doesn't support string (`<U20`) arrays.

Comment: Does the `cupy` docs talk about string dtype arrays?

Comment: `cupy` currently does not provide string support. See: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: So, in the datatypes, it does not list string simply because the datatype is not supported!!!